# How to add a directory to :scope options in clock report?

Tags: org-mode

I have a common file to track the time logged in multiple files across various directories. Manually adding files to `:scope` becomes tedious very quickly. How can I automatically add all the files in a given directory?

Comment: I've edited your question (pending review) to clarify it. If I misread your intent, feel free to edit it again yourself.

Comment: For close-vote reviewers, please note that the OP acknowledged the duplicate in a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question can be closed. I found the solution here.

[Is there a simple way to use all org-files referenced in a main file for the org-mode clock table](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5481/is-there-a-simple-way-to-use-all-org-files-referenced-in-a-main-file-for-the-org?rq=1)