# How can you set clocktable scope dynamically? Or call it programmatically?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

I want to get a clocktable for a list of files defined by a function, and I can't see a way to do that. In theory (according to this answer: [Is there a simple way to use all org-files referenced in a main file for the org-mode clock table](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5481/is-there-a-simple-way-to-use-all-org-files-referenced-in-a-main-file-for-the-org)) you can just provide a function, but it doesn't seem to work.

Alternatively, I'd be happy calling clocktable programmatically with elisp (and providing the function of files that way), but can't figure out how from my scan and attempts in `org-clock.el`.

For reference, here is an example function I would use to generate the list of files:

```
(load-library "find-lisp")
(defun current-dir-org-files () (find-lisp-find-files "." "\.org$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function, but there seems to be a simple mistake in the answer you linked to. Drop the brackets and it should work.

Or, refer to the answer I posted on your link: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38342/17462

Comment: I fixed the accepted answer in the link.