# Can I use a dynamic parameter for a org clocktable's "block" in BEGIN?

Tags: org-mode

I am generating monthly bills with org-mode which also includes a clocktable. The month ideally should be only defined once at the top of the file and the value then be used by any dynamic block.

Can I reference a variable like `#+Date: 2019-03` or the result of a src block from within the definition of my clocktable?

pseudo code:

```
#+NAME: get_block    
#+BEGIN_SRC python
return "2019-03"
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN: clocktable :block (get_block) ...
```

I saw something similar for `:scope` but would want something embedded in the file: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7903/21642